# make vim remember my most important command

Tags: vim

In vim there are lot of hotkeys, and it is need a lot of time to remember all of them. But there some commands which I don't use often and to use and remember another key sequence is not a need. On the other hand, to remember a hole command and write it even with completion is a good approach. Does somebody know a plugin or a script which explain how to make a list with important commands? It would be good if I can open this list, edit it and select commands.

Comment: You should ask it to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to know about command-line history: <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>, it lets you walk through the list and re-execute with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Further more, you describe a text file. **Vim is */good/* with textfiles** :)

Here is an idea to create a mapping that let's you execute a random line from a textfile as a command: (testing)

```
:nnoremap <C-CR> :exec getline(".")<CR>
```

(linked to <kbd>Ctrl-Enter</kbd> for example)

Answer (score 1):

Some people, me included, use wikis or lightweight blog engines to file away new tricks in a searchable manner as they are encountered. Others may use cross-plateform note taking programs. Others, like voithos, may use pencil and paper. Others don't care that much because they know those advanced tricks will be only a quick google away the next time they need it. Others know that everything and the rest is in `:help`, including that nifty trick they just saw in a screencast.

But what you really need is probably to edit and grow your `.vimrc`. Once you figure out a better way to do something add it there and give it a mapping. This file will grow along with your knowledge until you are confident enough to scrap most of it.

Comment: +1 for "until you are confident enough to scrap most of it" - I run mostly plain vanilla these days, since anything is only a few keys away :)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not "confident enough to scrap most of it" but it will happen.

Comment: I only ever have this: `syntax on|filetype plugin on|filetype indent on|behave xterm|se ar aw ts=4 sw=4 et`. Its tolerable since I can type it up in 15 seconds if I have to. In fact, these should be the defaults of course :) Oh, and `modeline` is nice